# Getting a DISTINCT value in a subquery

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, ms-access, group-by, migration

I have a recently been trying to convert the First() function from MS Access to T-SQL. Now First() does not exist in T-SQL so I've had to explore some alternatives. I Found the First_Value function which seems to do the job.

However, Take the code below:

```
SELECT [Order Transactions Table].[Job Number],
   [Order Transactions Table].OutstandingBalance,
   [Order Transactions Table].[Accepted Quantity],
   MRPStockOut.MRPStockOutID,
   MRPStockOut.[Date],
   MRPStockOut.[Units],
   MRPHeader.MRPHeaderID,
   FIRST_VALUE(MRPSupplier.StockCode) OVER (PARTITION BY MRPSupplier.StockCode ORDER BY MRPSupplier.StockCode) AS FirstOfStockCode,
   --(SELECT TOP (1) MRPSupplier.StockCode ORDER BY [Order Transactions Table].[Job Number]) AS FirstOfStockCode,
   MRPHeader.MaterialDescription,
   MRPStockOut.StockQtyOut,
   MRPHeader.WeightPerUnit * MRPStockOut.StockQtyOut AS [Weight],
   LiveWIPStockAllocatedToJobsPrices.PurchPriceEach,
   LiveWIPStockAllocatedToJobsPrices.StockPriceEach,
   LiveWIPStockAllocatedToJobsPrices.PriceEach,
   (IIF(ISNULL(LiveWIPStockAllocatedToJobsPrices.PurchPriceEach,0) > 0,
    ISNULL(LiveWIPStockAllocatedToJobsPrices.PurchPriceEach,0),
    ISNULL(LiveWIPStockAllocatedToJobsPrices.StockPriceEach,0)) +0) * MRPStockOut.StockQtyOut AS TotalPrice

FROM [Order Transactions Table]
INNER JOIN MRPStockOut ON [Order Transactions Table].[Job Number] = MRPStockOut.JobNumber
INNER JOIN MRPHeader ON MRPStockOut.MRPHeaderID = MRPHeader.MRPHeaderID
INNER JOIN LiveWIPStockAllocatedToJobsPrices ON MRPHeader.MRPHeaderID = 
LiveWIPStockAllocatedToJobsPrices.MRPHeaderID
INNER JOIN MRPSupplier ON MRPHeader.MRPHeaderID = MRPSupplier.MRPHeaderID
GROUP BY
[Order Transactions Table].[Job Number],
[Order Transactions Table].OutstandingBalance,
[Order Transactions Table].[Accepted Quantity],
MRPStockOut.MRPStockOutID,
MRPStockOut.[Date],
MRPStockOut.[Units],
MRPHeader.MRPHeaderID,
MRPSupplier.StockCode,
MRPHeader.MaterialDescription, 
MRPStockOut.StockQtyOut,
MRPHeader.WeightPerUnit * MRPStockOut.StockQtyOut,
LiveWIPStockAllocatedToJobsPrices.PurchPriceEach,
LiveWIPStockAllocatedToJobsPrices.StockPriceEach,
LiveWIPStockAllocatedToJobsPrices.PriceEach,
(IIF(ISNULL(LiveWIPStockAllocatedToJobsPrices.PurchPriceEach,0) > 0,
ISNULL(LiveWIPStockAllocatedToJobsPrices.PurchPriceEach,0),
ISNULL(LiveWIPStockAllocatedToJobsPrices.StockPriceEach,0)) +0) * MRPStockOut.StockQtyOut
Having [Order Transactions Table].OutstandingBalance > 0
```

Particularly the line to select the first value in MRPSupplier. (**First(MRPSupplier.StockCode)** in Access)

**FIRST_VALUE(MRPSupplier.StockCode) OVER (PARTITION BY MRPSupplier.StockCode ORDER BY MRPSupplier.StockCode) AS FirstOfStockCode**

Now this value is returning what that I am expecting, however, certain Jobs are come back with 2 records rather than one, under the same [Job Number]. This is because one of the duplicate jobs comes back with **FirstOfStockCode = Null** and the other has the expected value.

This is a problem because this is a subquery and I have a SUM on the query above which is giving me an incorrect because TotalPrice is being Summed twice due to the duplicate record. How can I get it so that I only receive a Distinct value from this column?

Edit:

Current Results:
[image: Current Results]

Expected Results are the only the 2nd record above is selected the First NULL record shouldn't be in the select list.

Edit 2:

Here is another screenshot of more records (546 rows - This is two more than I get in MS Access):
[image: More Records]

Again, These two Null value records should not be exist as they are duplicates
Edit 3:
User @Isaac has managed to help me resolve this. See comments thread in his answer.

Comment: Sample data and expected results will be helpful

Comment: @ShikharArora I have edited in a screenshot of the results I'm getting and also what I am expecting. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try replacing this line...

```
FIRST_VALUE(MRPSupplier.StockCode) OVER (PARTITION BY MRPSupplier.StockCode ORDER BY MRPSupplier.StockCode) AS FirstOfStockCode,
```

with this...

```
FIRST_VALUE(MRPSupplier.StockCode) OVER (ORDER BY MRPSupplier.StockCode) AS FirstOfStockCode,
```

I believe The PARTITION BY clause is causing the extra row to be returned. If that causes the row with a NULL value to be returned add **DESC** like this...

```
FIRST_VALUE(MRPSupplier.StockCode) OVER (ORDER BY MRPSupplier.StockCode DESC) AS FirstOfStockCode,
```

Comment: I tried this but i'm still getting 2 records, only now I'm getting both records having NULL in FirstOfStockCode and when I add DESC as you stated, I get both records, FirstOfStockCode as CZ121 12, making both records exactly identical. I need to have only one record returned.

Comment: Without test data for us to test with it is a bit difficult to troubleshoot. Despite that, the presence of MRPSupplier.StockCode in the GROUP BY seems like a problem. Try replacing that with the full line that is FirstOfStockCode. Does that make sense?

Comment: I can appreciate that it is difficult to be able to troubleshoot something like without having the data. I can however, keep taking screenshots of anything that you think I should try. Using the First_Value within a Group By is not allowed as it is a Windowed function than can only appear in SELECT'S and ORDER BY's unfortunately.

Comment: If you are getting two identical rows you could add **DISTINCT** immediately after your SELECT, but that may by masking the issue rather than solving it.

Comment: I think something is going wrong in my First_Value function, I don't believe the data is being aggregated correctly as I was not able to group by this column as it contains a Windowed function. I considered using **DISTINCT** but like you said, this only masks the problem. I still get the double calculation value when this query becomes a subquery. This is because I am grouping by Job Number on the query above. I need the NULL value records to not exist at all.

Comment: If NULL values for MRPSupplier.StockCode the only issue then can you just add a where clause to exclude them.

Comment: Of course! How did I miss something so simple? This has done the trick, my query above is now calculating correctly.First() in access seems to automatically ignore the NULL records, but First_Value doesn't do the same. Thanks!